# Logstash rename field with fileset.name

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am using Logstash 6.2.1, which collects the syslogs from Filebeat. I am receiving two fields (as seen in Kibana), `fileset.name` and `fileset.module` with the values *syslog* and *system* respectively. I wish to rename these fields in Logstash with the following filter

```
filter {
   mutate {
     rename => { "fileset.module" => "category"}
   }
}
```

but the field names does not change. I can change some of the other fields, it appears those with no fullstops in their names.

Comment: try this `rename => { "[fileset][module]" => "category"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of Stack Overflow format:
this worked: 
`rename => { "[fileset][module]" => "category"}`,, mentioned by [TheUknown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2196341/theuknown).